# sorting files on linux

Tags: bash, sorting

I have multiple files in a directory they have numeric digits before their extensions. like below:

- SHG_PS_RG_10.tif
- ABC_MFCL_NHG_PS_RG_af_04.tif
- SHG_PS_RG_af_01.tif
- CBC_MFCL_NHG_PS_RG_af_03.tif

etc..
I want to sort them with the numeric (01,03,04 etc) like below:

- SHG_PS_RG_af_01.tif
- CBC_MFCL_NHG_PS_RG_af_03.tif
- ABC_MFCL_NHG_PS_RG_af_04.tif
- SHG_PS_RG_10.tif

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
nifle@megamart ~/tmp
$ echo "SHG_PS_RG_10.tif
  ABC_MFCL_NHG_PS_RG_af_04.tif
  SHG_PS_RG_af_01.tif
  CBC_MFCL_NHG_PS_RG_af_03.tif" > foo.txt

nifle@megamart ~/tmp
$ awk -F "_" '{print $NF,$0}' foo.txt  | sort -n | cut -f2- -d' '

SHG_PS_RG_af_01.tif
CBC_MFCL_NHG_PS_RG_af_03.tif
ABC_MFCL_NHG_PS_RG_af_04.tif
SHG_PS_RG_10.tif
```

Explanation

- `-F "_"` tells awk that we use '_' as a field separator
- `$NF` is *awk'ish* for the last field `10.tif`
- `$0` is *awk'ish* for the whole input `SHG_PS_RG_af_01.tif`
- so this `'{print $NF,$0}'` prints `10.tif SHG_PS_RG_10.tif`

  When we have  `10.tif SHG_PS_RG_10.tif` it's easy to do `sort -n` and then we use `cut -f2- -d' '` to print out only the second column.

Comment: Thanks but i forgot to ask that i have spaces in the names of files like  "SHG_PS RG_10.tif ". in this case what should i do ? how will we tell awk that in some files we have space and in other files we have underscore as field seperator. please propose a solution

Comment: I tried the command 
ls -1 *af* | tr -s ' ' '_' | awk -F '_' '{print $NF , $0}' | sort -n | cut -f2 -d' 
and it worked ! :)
Thanks.